# Finding two minimum spanning trees in graph such that their sum is minimal

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

I'm trying to solve pretty complex problem with graphs, namely we have given undirected graph with *N*(*N <= 10*)nodes and *M* (*M <= 25*)edges.

Let's say we have two sets of edges A and B, we can't have two same edges in both A and B, also there can be edges that wont be used in the any of those sets, each edge is assigned value to it. We want to minimize the total sum of the two trees.

Please note that in both sets A and B the edges should form connected graph with all N nodes.

**Example**

N = 2, M = 3

Edges: 1 - 2, value = 10, 1 - 2, value: 20, 2 - 1, value 30, we want to return the result 30, in the set A we take the first edge and in set B the second edge.

N = 5
M = 8

Edges: {
 (1,2,10),
 (1,3,10),
 (1,4,10),
 (1,4,20),
 (1,5,20),
 (2,3,20),
 (3,4,20),
 (4,5,30),
}

set A contains edges {(1,2,10), (1,3,10), (1,4,10), (1,5,20)}

while set B contains {(1,4,20), (2,3,20), (3,4,20), (4,5,30)}

**What I tried**

Firstly I coded greedy solution, I first generated the first minimum spanning tree and then I generated with the other edges the second one, but it fails on some test cases. So I started thinking about this solution:

We can see that we want to split the edges in two groups, also we can see that in each group we want to have N - 1 edges to make sure the graph doesn't contain not-wanted edges, Now we see that in worse-case we will use (N-1) + (N-1) edges, that is 18 edges. This is small numbers, so we can run backtracking algorithm with some optimizations to solve this problem.

I still haven't coded the backtracking because I'm not sure if it will work, please write what do you think. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the problem to generate two distinct spanning trees (sharing at most one edge? or no edges at all?) such that the sum of all edges in both trees is minimized? Does the caller determine which edges are in A and B, or does the algorithm make that determination as part of its minimization process? If the former, generating MSTs for each of A and B should be correct. If the latter, as I imagine, the problem is indeed harder and backtracking of some kind (visiting no more than 2^|E| divisions and producing MSTs) will work but may not optimal.

Comment: The two trees must not share any edges, they should be with distinct edges.

Comment: Thanks. And does the division of edges into groups A and B happen outside the algorithm, or is the algorithm responsible for determining the groups to produce spanning trees which have minimal combined sum?

Comment: The algorithm should produce the sum ( divide the edges )

Comment: Can you show an example where the greedy approach fails?

Comment: Actually I cant provide example because i dont really understand why the greedy solution fails

Comment: I guess you have a time limit? and what is it?

Comment: The time limit is 3.00 seconds

Comment: @someone12321 I guess a simple brute force may be enough if we have 3s. We try all ways to divide the edges into two sets. There will be at most 2 ^ 25 ways, and for each way, we find the sum of cost to construct mst in both two sets. Finally we just return the minimum cost. Is the problem publicly available? If yes can you post the link because I also want to try it.

Comment: @PetarPetrovic here is the link: https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=1748 btw I solved it already with doing backtracking.